# Add content of a url to respondText in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have a [url](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) that i want to display as the content of my webpage using **Ktor** framework.

```
fun Application.module() {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(Routing) {

        get("/") {
            call.respondText(/*Content of that url in the output ?*/, ContentType.Text.Any)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a kind of a proxy. You can check a reverse proxy sample here: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/master/other/reverse-proxy